# angular 2 RC4- Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Router'

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, angular, mocking

I have written a test for my component and it is failing with

> Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Router'(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or
>   have valid type annotations and that 'Router' is decorated with
>   Injectable.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Supplier } from './supplier';
import { SupplierService } from './supplier.service';
import { AppService } from '../shared/app.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'supplier-form',
    templateUrl: './supplier-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./supplier-form.component.css']
})
export class SupplierFormComponent implements OnInit {

    private countries: any;
    private model: Supplier;
    private errorMessage: string;
    private submitted: boolean = false;
    private active: boolean = true;

    constructor(private appService: AppService, private supplierService: SupplierService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.model = new Supplier();
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
            if (!isNaN(id))
                this.supplierService.getSupplierById(id)
                    .subscribe(supplier => this.model = supplier, error => this.errorMessage = error);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getCountries();
    }

    private getCountries() {
        this.appService.getCountry()
            .subscribe(countries => this.countries = countries.items,
            error => this.errorMessage = error);
    }

    private navigateToHomePage(supplier) {
        if (supplier) {
            let link = [''];
            this.router.navigate(link);
        }
    }

    private onSubmit(): void {
        this.submitted = true;
        this.supplierService.saveSupplier(this.model).subscribe(
            supplier => this.navigateToHomePage(supplier),
            error => this.errorMessage = error);
    }
}
```

very simple component all its doing is getting countries from a service which is using Http call and calling save method on another service which is also http call. I am mocking those services with my Mock classes. below is my test code.

```
import { By }           from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

import {
    beforeEach, beforeEachProviders,
    describe, xdescribe,
    expect, it, xit,
    async, inject, addProviders,
    TestComponentBuilder, ComponentFixture
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { SupplierFormComponent } from './supplier-form.component';
import { SupplierService } from './supplier.service';
import { AppService } from '../shared/app.service';

describe('Component: Supplier', () => {

    var builder;

    beforeEachProviders(() => {
        return [
            disableDeprecatedForms(),
            provideForms(),
            Router, ActivatedRoute,
            provide(AppService, { useClass: MockAppService }),
            provide(SupplierService, { useClass: MockSupplierService })
        ];
    });

    beforeEach(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
        builder = tcb;
    }));

    it('should create Supplier Component', async(() => {
        /*.overrideProviders(
            SupplierFormComponent,
            [{ provide: AppService, useClass: MockAppService }]
        )*/
        builder.createAsync(SupplierFormComponent)
            .then((fixture: ComponentFixture<SupplierFormComponent>) => {
                fixture.detectChanges
                var compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
                console.log(compiled);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("error occured: " + error);
            });
    }));

});

class MockAppService {
    public name = "Injected App Service";
    public fakeResponse: any = [{ "id": 1, "name": "uk" }];

    public getCountry() {
        return this.fakeResponse;
    }

}

class MockSupplierService {
    public name = "Injected Supplier Service";
    saveSupplier(supplier: any): boolean {
    return true;
    }
}
```

any idea how can i mock router properly with RC.4.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you found a solution for that ?

Comment: nope, not yet :( this question has been almost 5 days old and no response.

Comment: Hi there! There have been a lot of changes on testing APIs (beforeEachProviders is gone and also AddProviders). I would recommend you to give it another try now after RC5. Read the release notes and specifically tests for the router in the Angular 2 repo. I tried myself to get something working for RC4 but it required some specific Mocks. Now it's supposed to be sorted but haven't got the time to go through the details yet.

Comment: @GerardSans
thanks for the input. I will update to RC5 and see if it breaks my website first and will try testing. see you on Tuesday weekly meeting :)

Comment: This will help https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed/commit/2b35e388006db3a23d49039b50d908ba5043ee5b